# Will React hooks completely replace the class based component creation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Will react hooks completely replace the class based component creation. Will companies adopt the react hooks in near future?. Should I learn react hooks?

Comment: this isn't really the place to canvas opinions, but signs point to 'yes' :-)

Comment: (1) that will probably take some time (2) probably (3) yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Hooks docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html):

> There are no plans to remove classes from React.

The docs also discuss a [gradual adoption strategy](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#gradual-adoption-strategy) for Hooks.

I found Hooks to be confusing at first, but well worth learning. I've almost completely moved from classes to Hooks in my projects.

According to a recent [poll on Twitter](https://twitter.com/kentcdodds/status/1137044918537412608) (not scientific to be sure), Hooks are becoming heavily adopted by developers that are new to React.